# was unexpected at this time in basic if then statement

Tags: file, if-statement, batch-file, exists

I am trying this and can not get it to work ? Get datareal\copiesdonotdelete.txt was unexpected at this time.

```
rem @echo off
if exists datareal\copiesdonotdelete.txt goto DoFunction1
Goto DoFunction2
Exit
:DOFunction1
rename data datatemp
rename datareal data
rename datatemp datacopyfiles
Echo Done
Exit
:DOFunction2
 rename data datatemp
 rename datacopyfiles data
 rename datatemp datareal
 Echo Done
 Exit
```

Answer (score 10):

Its exist not exists

```
if exist datareal\copiesdonotdelete.txt goto DoFunction1
```